# Auto Fix is enabled by default. Use the single string form

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

When I configure my vscode with eslint & prettier, I met a problem in .settings.json file with error message **"Auto Fix is enabled by default. Use the single string form."**:
[image]

My eslint configuration is:

[image]

My prettier configuration is:

```js
module.exports = {
  singleQuote: true,
  semi: false
}
```

Does anybody know what's the reason and how to fix?

Comment: Fixing the indentation might help?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the error message, it says: "Auto Fix is enabled by default. Use the single string form." And I also tried the tabWidth:4, but it doesn't work for .settings.json file.

Answer (score 63):

It seems a tab width issue, try add `"tabWidth": 4` in your prettier config.

**EDIT:**

According to [ESLint Reference](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint): "eslint.validate" is an array of language identifiers specifying the files for which validation is to be **enforced**.

"eslint.validate" accept an array of language identifiers, not an array of objects.

No need for "autoFix", it defaults to be true.

So your settings should be:

```
"eslint.validate": [
    "vue",
    "html",
    "javascript"
]
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the error message, it says: "Auto Fix is enabled by default. Use the single string form." And I also tried the tabWidth:4, but it doesn't work for .settings.json file.

Comment: This answer is correct. You should mention `"eslint.validate": ["vue", "html", "javascript"]` instead of array of objects.